# "failed to commit changes to dconf: The connection is closed"

Tags: dconf

I'm following someone's instructions for solving this problem on Fedora:

```
dconf-WARNING **: failed to commit changes to dconf: The connection is closed
```

Apparently this is caused by a corrupt config file that I should try to rename. The person suggest I go to:

```
~/.config/dconf/
```

But that directory doesn't exist on my fresh Fedora 20 install. I just moved over from Debian, where I'd used that directory a few times.

Should I be worried that `.config` doesn't exist on my install? Especially since I'm following a guide for Fedora 20 that assumes it's there.

How can I proceed to fix my problem?

Comment: On many systems I've been working on, I often had to create this directory myself :)

Comment: See [Redhat's Official Bug - 975521](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=975521)